# Push queue, modules and dispatch file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, queue, dispatch

I'm passing messages to a push queue `(url="/push/ios")` and I have a dispatch file that handles `/push/*` to my push module.

Yet, the URL is re-routed towards my default module, while it works fine if I curl `myapp.appspot.com/push/ios`.

The doc seems to agree with this behaviour

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue

> Note: If you are using modules along with a dispatch file, your task's HTTP request may be intercepted and re-routed to another module.

Is there a way to solve this and to have push queues efficiently working with modules + dispatch files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the `target` parameter to tell GAE where to execute the task:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#target

Comment: Works perfectly, don't know how I missed that :) Thanks!